# Unable to built Bochdbg

Tags: system-installation

I am a new comer to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 from Windows.

I tried to built *bochs 2.6.9* from source and i am unable to install the debugger. I tried a lot of configurations but the result is always the same. The system keeps coming with the following message:

```
install: cannot stat './bochsdbg': No such file or directory
Makefile:429: recipe for target 'install_bin' failed
```

Bochs is installed properly `/usr/local/bin`, but is useless to me without the debugger.